# Define $f(x)=mx+b$ for all $x$. Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Define $f(x)=mx+b$ for all $x$. Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

---

Let $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ be sequences of $\mathbb{R}$ and converges to $x_0$, then we have $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (u_n-v_n)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} u_n-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} v_n = x_0-x_0=0$$ next we have: $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (f(u_n)-f(v_n))=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(u_n)-\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(v_n)=(mx_0+b)-(mx_0+b)=0$$

Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous.

---

Can anyone check my solution? I am not sure that I have show enough information, I just follow the definition. Thanks

Comment: The proof of continuity looks ok. But uniform continuity is a much stronger notion, which you haven't yet proved.

Comment: Use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition you got in your lecture for sure. It is a straightforward calculation and a good opportunity to really understand the definition.

Comment: @NateRiver Can you give me a hit about how to show $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: @JohnSmith I haven't covered $\epsilon-\delta$ definition yet

Comment: Ok, how did you define uniform continuity?

Comment: @JohnSmith Whenever $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ are sequence in the domain such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (u_n-v_n)=0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} (f(u_n)-f(v_n))=0$

Comment: The problem with your argument is that you assume ${u_n}$ and ${v_n}$ converge to some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Try to see what happens if you only assume $\vert u_n-v_n\vert \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @NateRiver By the triangle inequality, I will get a sum, right?

Comment: Typically, yes. But for linear functions it is simpler. See John Smith's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already shown continuity. I'll stick to your definition. Let $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ be real sequences with $\lim_{n\to\infty} \vert u_n-v_n \vert=0$. We have:
$$\vert f(u_n)-f(v_n)\vert=\vert mu_n+b-mv_n-b\vert = \vert m(u_n-v_n) \vert \to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Dear @John I've made some necessary edits in your answer,hope you will not mind it.

Comment: @ArpitKansal Sure, whatever is needed for clarification should be added!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  For any $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$,note that $\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \leq m \vert x-y \vert$.Hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous which is stronger than uniform Continuity.